# In AutoMapper, read only collection properties on the destination type are not automatically ignored

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm using AutoMapper v9.0.0.  Since non-collection read only properties (properties with getters only) are automatically ignored on the destination type, I was expecting the same to be true for collection properties.  However, an exception is thrown when asserting the mapper configuration.  To further clarify, see the code below.  Is this by design or is this a bug?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<SourceType, DestinationTypeWithGetterOnly>();
        });

        //valid
        config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

        config = new AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<SourceType, DestinationTypeWithGetterOnlyArray>();
        });

        //throws exception Unmapped properties: CalculatedArray
        config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }
}

class SourceType { }

class DestinationTypeWithGetterOnlyArray
{
    public string[] CalculatedArray => new string[0];
}

class DestinationTypeWithGetterOnly
{
    public string CalculatedProperty => string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: It kinda make sense as you can fill the array elements with values.

Comment: In 10.0 all collections properties without setter will be mapped by default.

Answer (score -1):

Quoting @LucianBargaoanu on [github](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/3449#issuecomment-651522397)

By design. You can use `ForAllMaps` and `ForAllMembers` or `ForAllPropertyMaps` to achieve what you want. Or maybe `ShouldMapField`\ `ShouldMapProperty`. For example,

```
cfg.ShouldMapProperty = property => property.CanWrite;
```